# Python flask json, i have a list of dictionaries i need to load and then return them as a table in html

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary, flask

I have a json file where the data is a list with dictionaries as data
What i need to do is take index 0 for instance, and return the firstname, mail and username keys values.
the json data is like this: [{},{},{},{}]

this is my code right now:

```
@app.route("/showallusers")
def show_users():
temp_list = []
with open("users.json") as file:
    file = json.load(file)

res = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>Brugernavn</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
"""

i = 0

for i in len(file):
    res += """<tr>"""
    j = 0
    for j in len(file):
        res += """<td>""" f"{file[i]}" """</td>"""
    res += """</tr>"""
res += """
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""
return res
```

the table should look like this and should repeat adding tablerows with table data for each dictionary in the list:
|Name|Username|Mail|
|:---|--------|--------------|
|bob|bob1234 |bob@gmaill.com|

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier for you to make it into a JINJA2 template and generate HTML using that. https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop will change into something like this:

```
for row in file:
    res += """<tr>"""
    for key, value in row.items():
        res += f"""<td> {value} </td>"""
    res += """</tr>"""
```

Comment: With this for loop i get out on the brower, but it makes too many table data cells to the right with no theaders, and it only need to be 3 columns wide

`for i in range(0,len(file)):
        my_dict = file[i]
        res += """<tr>"""
        for key in (my_dict):
            res += """<td>""" f"{my_dict['firstname'] + ' ' + my_dict['lastname']}" """</td>"""
            res += """<td>""" f"{my_dict['username']}" """</td>"""
            res += """<td>""" f"{my_dict['mail']}" """</td>"""
        res += """</tr>"""`

Comment: got it to work with some tweeks